# Geometrical task and code documentation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone!
It's not a question about ROS, but I think many of you met the same problem. I have been writing code that have a part to solve some complicate geometrical problem. The problem had been solved on a sketch by me and I replaced the solution in the code using variable name according to that I use on the sheet. After few week I have lost my sketch and the solution too.. but when I look at the code I have no idea how I have solved it and that all these variables mean. Comments are useful no so better than variable names. And I really need to solve the problem again to understand how it works.

Perhaps someone knows instruments or practices to do the code more self-documented in this case.

Thanks, Aleksey.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94696/geometrical-task-and-code-documentation/) by [flipback](https://answers.ros.org/users/7831/flipback/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an off-topic question, you might actually have better luck asking on stackoverflow or some other coding forum.  But to weigh in a bit, one of the things that I find helps me a lot is to keep all of my code under version control.  I personally use git, and in your situation, I would have made several commits while I was originally writing the code.  In those commits, I would have made detailed notes to myself about what I was doing, and what my thought process was.  Then I can always see how I arrived at my answer.  Comments, code structure, and variable names can all be utilized (and should be) to write code whose purpose is self-evident, but documenting the evolution of the code and your own thoughts can be a useful tool during development.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flipback](https://answers.ros.org/users/7831/flipback/) on 2013-10-27**:
Thanks for answer. I absolutely agree with you. But then one solves a geometrical task it is more helpful using a sketch than comments. And the question is about how include a sketch to code or project better.